# How to remove unwanted features in R?

Tags: r, feature-selection

Suppose I have the following `data`:

```
             'aaa'     'a'     'aaron'     'abcde'     'azz'
        x1    ...      ...       ...         ...        ...
        x2    ...      ...       ...         ...        ...
        x3    ...      ...       ...         ...        ...
```

Given a pre-defined list of English words , how can I use the `which(.. %in% ..)` operator to get the vector position in order to retain only the features that exist in the pre-defined list of English words?

Expected output:

```
     'a'     'aaron'    
x1    ...      ...       
x2    ...      ...      
x3    ...      ...
```

Comment: Not very clear.  Please explain a bit more clearly.  If you have a vector of names i.e. `v1` then, `df1[,colnames(df1) %in% v1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of column names you want to keep you can run this:

```
dat = dat[, colnames(dat) %in% list]
```

If you have a list of column names you do not want to keep you can run this:

```
dat = dat[, !(colnames(dat) %in% list)]
```

If you're using a data.table you're going to have to include with=FALSE for this to work.

```
dat = dat[, colnames(dat) %in% list, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: Using which(.) around the logical vector is not such a good idea. Keep indexing with the logical vector that `%in%` produces.   Then, even more importantly,  `-which(..)`  is *dangerous*, it badly fails when there is no match, where   `!(...<your logical> ..)`  works perfectly in that case. @akrun's answer is better

Comment: @MartinMächler Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the code. Can you explain why indexing with logical vectors is bad? I know it's not necessary, but will it actually cause errors or performance issues?

Answer (score 4):

If we have a vector of names, then use `%in%`

```
df1[,colnames(df1) %in% v1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Using `which`, you can get a vector of desired column positions, and then select just the desired columns:

```
cols <- which(colnames(data) %in% list)
data[cols]
```

A different approach is to use dplyr's select:

```
data %>% select_(.dots = list)
```

Answer (score 1):

(A long answer to the question by @Kristofersen yesterday) It's the reverse: indexing with logical vectors is *good* and safer: I gave one important reason already above: "-which(...)". Please do try to produce such a 'no match' example and see for yourself.
2nd reason:  Handling of (accidental) NA's:  If your logical vector contains NA's -- which(.) all eliminates them and you do not notice that something is "strange" with your data (because that's typically the reason for NA's in a logical vector.
A third reason: You can easily and/or (i.e. `&` , `|`) logical vectors when new conditions for selection come up. The equivalent for integer index vectors is more error prone ((though you can often work with union() / intersect() / setdiff() there..))   Keeping things logical is cleaner and safer,  and using   `which(.)` around logical vectors for indexing is a **bad** practice, seen in too many places in R code.  I don't have time for a "lecture" on this right now, sorry.